# Is there sportbike equipment in GTA5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I am looking for sportbike suits like racers in MotoGP have.
Something like this https://www.infinitymotorcycles.com/images/products/medium/3_Dainese_Avro_Leather_Suit_Blue.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The racing outfits are only obtainable in the Online portion of GTA V.